# my question is a networking question about the way data encapsulation and tunneling, why did you remove it from networking section?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Network Engineering Stack Exchange post: [why some proxies use localhost IP 127.0.0.0.1 instead of connecting directly to the remote server?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/78339/why-some-proxies-use-localhost-ip-127-0-0-0-1-instead-of-connecting-directly-to)

Answer (score 1):

Questions about hosts/servers, applications, and protocols above OSI layer-4 are all off-topic on [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/). Proxies are applications on proxy servers, and you must configure applications to use them. Also, the vendor does not offer optional, paid support, which is a requirement.

There really is nothing on-topic about your question.

There are other SE sites on which you could ask the question: [Super User](https://superuser.com/) for a home/residential network, or [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) for a business network.

Answer (score 0):

Basically  when ipsec site to site vpn tunnel is configured between two remote peer which are connected in internet  .. to ensure communication between two peer with private ips,it has to be encapsulated means covering packet and adding extra ip headed with public ips which are routeable in internet .. encapsulation is mainly required for security reasons and because private ips  are not routeable in internet .. ESP is used for encapsulation which provides confidentiality, integrity, authentic action .